# Update a profile in the database form with prisma and nextjs

Tags: typescript, forms, next.js, prisma, zod

I have made a profile creator, and I won't a user to be able to update their profile just like in twitte rtheir past details to be the value of the form inputs and they can be changed and even if one of them isn't changed you can still submit the form for now I have put the past details as placholeders of the inputs, but you have to update everything to submit

So, here is my page.tsx file for the form:

```
"use client";

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

import * as z from "zod";
import { formSchema } from "@/app/create-profile/constants";
import { UploadDropzone } from "@/app/utils/uploadthing";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormDescription,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
} from "@/components/ui/form";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Textarea } from "@/components/ui/textarea";
import { Separator } from "@/components/ui/separator";
import axios from "axios";
import { auth, useAuth } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import prismadb from "@/lib/prisma";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { checkProfile } from "@/app/actions/check";

interface UserProfile {
  id: string;
  userId: string;
  fullName: string;
  email: string;
  age: string;
  src: string;
  Education: string;
  PastPosition: string;
  Skills: string;
  TechStack?: string;
  AboutMe: string;
  Country: string;
  LinkedIn: string;
  Github?: string;
  Instagram?: string;
  Twitter?: string;
  createdAt: Date;
}

const ProfileForm = () => {
  const { userId } = useAuth();
  const router = useRouter();
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState<UserProfile>(Object);
  const [formInitialized, setFormInitialized] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProfile = async () => {
      const userProfile = await checkProfile(userId);
      if (userProfile) {
        setProfile(userProfile);
        setFormInitialized(true);
      }
    };
    fetchProfile();
  }, []);

  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      fullName: profile.fullName,
      email: profile?.email,
      age: profile?.age,
      src: profile?.src,
      Education: profile?.Education,
      PastPosition: profile?.PastPosition,
      Skills: profile?.Skills,
      TechStack: profile?.TechStack,
      AboutMe: profile?.AboutMe,
      Country: profile?.Country,
      LinkedIn: profile?.LinkedIn,
      GitHub: profile?.Github,
      Instagram: profile?.Instagram,
      Twitter: profile?.Twitter,
    },
  });

  const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("/api/update", {
        fullName: values.fullName || profile.fullName,
        email: values.email === "" ? profile.email : values.email,
        age: values.age || profile?.age,
        src: values.src || profile?.src,
        Education: values.Education || profile?.Education,
        PastPosition: values.PastPosition || profile?.PastPosition,
        Skills: values.Skills || profile?.Skills,
        TechStack: values.TechStack || profile?.TechStack,
        AboutMe: values.AboutMe || profile?.AboutMe,
        Country: values.Country || profile?.Country,
        LinkedIn: values.LinkedIn || profile?.LinkedIn,
        GitHub: values.GitHub || profile?.Github,
        Instagram: values.Instagram || profile?.Instagram,
        Twitter: values.Twitter || profile?.Twitter,
      });
      form.reset();
      router.push("/profiles");
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className=" w-screenl text-center break-normal">
        You have to update everything we are working on this bug.If you don't
        want to update something just put the same thing
      </h1>
      <UploadDropzone
        endpoint="imageUploader"
        className="w-[350px] block m-auto mt-2 bg-white border-black border-4 border-solid ut-label:text-black ut-button:bg-black ut-button:text-white ut-button:block ut-button:m-auto"
        onClientUploadComplete={(res) => {
          form.setValue("src", String(res[0].url));
          console.log(form.getValues("src"));
        }}
        onUploadError={(error: Error) => {
          // Do something with the error.
          alert(`ERROR! ${error.message}`);
        }}
      />
      <Form {...form}>
        <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <FormField
            name="fullName"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="w-[350px] block m-auto">
                <FormLabel>Username</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input placeholder={profile.fullName} {...field} />
                </FormControl>
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            name="age"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="w-[350px] block m-auto">
                <FormLabel>Age</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input placeholder={profile.age} {...field} />
                </FormControl>
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            name="email"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="w-[350px] block m-auto">
                <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input placeholder={profile.email} {...field} type="email" />
                </FormControl>
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            name="Education"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="w-[350px] block m-auto">
                <FormLabel>Education</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input placeholder={profile.Education} {...field} />
                </FormControl>
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            name="PastPosition"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="w-[350px] block m-auto">
                <FormLabel>Job</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input placeholder={profile.PastPosition} {...field} />
                </FormControl>
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            name="Skills"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="w-[350px] block m-auto">
                <FormLabel>Skills</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input placeholder={profile.Skills} {...field} />
                </FormControl>
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            name="Country"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="w-[350px] block m-auto">
                <FormLabel>Place of living</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input placeholder={profile.Country} {...field} />
                </FormControl>
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            name="TechStack"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="w-[350px] block m-auto">
                <FormLabel>TechStack</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input
                    placeholder={profile.TechStack || "Tech Stack"}
                    {...field}
                  />
                </FormControl>
                <FormDescription>optional</FormDescription>
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <h1 className="text-center font-bold text-zinc-800">About You</h1>
          <Separator className="h-1 bg-zinc-800 w-[500px] block m-auto my-3" />

          <FormField
            name="AboutMe"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="w-[350px] block m-auto">
                <FormControl>
                  <Textarea rows={4} placeholder={profile.AboutMe} {...field} />
                </FormControl>
                <FormDescription>required</FormDescription>
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <h1 className="text-center font-bold text-zinc-800">
            Your Social Media
          </h1>
          <Separator className="h-1 bg-zinc-800 w-[500px] block m-auto my-3" />
          <FormField
            name="LinkedIn"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="w-[350px] block m-auto">
                <FormLabel>Yout LinkedIn</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input
                    placeholder={profile.LinkedIn || "https://linkedin.com/you"}
                    {...field}
                  />
                </FormControl>
                <FormDescription>required</FormDescription>
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            name="GitHub"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="w-[350px] block m-auto">
                <FormLabel>Yout GitHub</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input
                    placeholder={profile.Github || "https://github.com/you"}
                    {...field}
                  />
                </FormControl>
                <FormDescription>optional</FormDescription>
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            name="Instagram"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="w-[350px] block m-auto">
                <FormLabel>Yout Instagram</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input
                    placeholder={
                      profile.Instagram || "https://instagram.com/you"
                    }
                    {...field}
                  />
                </FormControl>
                <FormDescription>optional</FormDescription>
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            name="Twitter"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="w-[350px] block m-auto">
                <FormLabel>Yout Twitter/X</FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input
                    placeholder={profile.Twitter || "https://twitter.com/you"}
                    {...field}
                  />
                </FormControl>
                <FormDescription>optional</FormDescription>
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <Button type="submit" className="block m-auto my-3">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </form>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProfileForm;
```

and my constants.ts aka my formSchema cus I am using zod:

```
import * as z from "zod";

export const formSchema = z.object({
  fullName: z
    .string()
    .min(4, {
      message: "Name is required",
    })
    .optional(),
  email: z.string().email().optional(),
  age: z
    .string()
    .min(1, {
      message: "Age is required",
    })
    .optional(),
  src: z.string().optional(),
  Education: z
    .string()
    .min(3, {
      message: "Education is required",
    })
    .optional(),
  PastPosition: z
    .string()
    .min(2, {
      message: "Postion is required",
    })
    .optional(),
  Skills: z
    .string()
    .min(2, {
      message: "Skills is required",
    })
    .optional(),
  TechStack: z
    .string()
    .min(3, {
      message: "TechStack needs to be atleast 3 characters",
    })
    .optional(),
  AboutMe: z
    .string()
    .min(20, {
      message: "AboutMe is required",
    })
    .optional(),
  Country: z
    .string()
    .min(1, {
      message: "Country is required",
    })
    .optional(),
  LinkedIn: z.string().optional(),
  GitHub: z.string().optional(),
  Instagram: z.string().optional(),
  Twitter: z.string().optional(),
});
```

My question is can you help for the user to be able to update the valuse of the inputs if some of the inputs aren't changed you can still submit with the new values of the inputs you changed and for the ones that aren't changed to be
submited with the past values
Oh, yeah here is my api route for updating:

```
import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import prismadb from "@/lib/prisma";

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  try {
    const { userId } = auth();
    const body = await req.json();
    const {
      fullName,
      email,
      age,
      src,
      Education,
      PastPosition,
      Skills,
      TechStack,
      AboutMe,
      Country,
      LinkedIn,
      GitHub,
      Instagram,
      Twitter,
    } = body;

    if (!userId) {
      return new NextResponse("Unauthorized", { status: 401 });
    }
    await prismadb.profile.update({
      where: {
        userId: userId,
      },
      data: {
        userId: userId,
        fullName: fullName,
        email: email,
        age: age,
        src: src,
        Education: Education,
        PastPosition: PastPosition,
        Skills: Skills,
        TechStack: TechStack,
        AboutMe: AboutMe,
        Country: Country,
        LinkedIn: LinkedIn,
        Github: GitHub,
        Instagram: Instagram,
        Twitter: Twitter,
      },
    });

    return new NextResponse("Success", { status: 201 });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```